# SQL server: select and join table where relationship is varchar and unique identifier

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I got this below table from database. I'm quite new guys in this field, so I don't understand how to join table when they used '**unique identifier**' in the table as relationship where **user_login_id (varchar(20))** and **id (uniqueidentifier)**.

[image]

#### Table: user_lookup

```
 username | user_type | user_login_id
-------------------------------------
 jdoe     | Type_A    | ultimate
```

#### Table: receiver

```
 id                                   | username | name
-----------------------------------------------------------
 10D3C530-B1FA-41B8-A9F6-6C9B84B10DC5 | jdoe     | john doe
```

How do I join this table **ON user_lookup.user_login_id = receiver.id**. I try below code but didn't get any result. Can anyone help me? thanks

```
SELECT *
FROM user_lookup tabA
    JOIN receiver tabB
    ON tabA.user_login_id = CAST(tabB.id AS VARCHAR(50))
WHERE tabA.username = 'ultimate'
```

Comment: whoever designed that schema relationship from varchar(20) to uniqueidentifier ....fire immediately

Comment: Because `ultimate` <> `10D3C530-B1FA-41B8-A9F6-6C9B84B10DC5`.

Comment: These columns cannot be joined together. Review your requirements. Join is mostly used between primary key column and a foreign key column in another table. That is not the case in your problem.

Comment: So I can't join this table? This table has been used for a few years already,  wonder why it still functioning well.

Comment: @MitchWheat you made laugh so hard in the Monday morning ->thank you ! :)

Comment: @saf21 - How are these two tables related ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only common column I found between two table is `username`

```
SELECT *
FROM user_lookup tabA
    JOIN receiver tabB
    ON tabA.username = tabB.username 
WHERE tabA.user_login_id = 'ultimate'
```

Comment: Yup, I'm using this one also. But there is a condition where this statement cannot working. For the time being I will do this first before I ask the guys that create this table. Anyway, thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the link would be on username, and userType would be ultimate

```
SELECT *
FROM user_lookup tabA
JOIN receiver    tabB  ON tabA.username = tabB.username
WHERE tabA.usertype = 'ultimate'
```